# Clean POST and GET variable with Symfony

Tags: php, security, symfony, input, request

I'm using Silex, which is using the component `Request` from Symfony. 
When I get the data sent from a form, for example this way:

```
$params = $request->request->all();
```

No thing is cleaned. Unlike Laravel where the user input data is cleaned automatically. Should I do it manually, with built PHP functions like `strip_tag` or there's a symfony way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by *clean*? Remove *dangerous* code?

Comment: And how does your form look like?

Comment: My form is just a normal HTML form, with input fields. By cleaning the data I mean remove HTML and JavaScript for instance.

Answer (score 8):

So basically when it comes to sanitizing input, it should not be a part of the Request. This is because, sanitized input is really only a part of the security of your database.

As such, input is sanitized by Doctrine when it's passed to Doctrine. Basically, Doctrine automatically makes sure all input is sanitized. In broader sense, it is the responsibility of your Database Abstraction Layer to make sure that data passed to it is valid.

The same holds true for Propel.

So what I'm saying is that input sanitizing is not the **responsibility** of the Request object, so it does not provide the functionality to do so. This is in line with the Single Responsibility Principle, which you can read more about here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

If you want to validate data that is received through a Request, you can use the Validator Component to do so, there is also a Silex ServiceProvider for it:
https://github.com/symfony/Validator

TLDR;
Sanitizing input is not the responsbility of the Request, it is the responsibility of your DBAL(Database Abastraction Layer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm using propel2 as an ORM, I don't know it if does clean the data before storing, to avoid SQL injection for instance.

Comment: As far as I understand, Propel 2 is indeed safe in this regard since it uses Prepared Statements. I have updated my answer to include this, please review if it answers your question correctly :)

Comment: Beyond Database Abastraction Layer, input must be sanitized since there are attack vectors that can exploit a site and do not even save information in the database.

Comment: You are correct, I did a faulty assumption of scope to only cover input that is passed to the database, in other cases, the responsibility would be on whoever is consuming the user input, still not part of the Request though.